# How can I convert an object to an array manually without using the json_decode($object, true) function?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

For some reason, the `json_decode($a)` function works fine in my work, but not when it has the true parameter `json_decode($a, true)`  that allows me to convert the object to an array. So I ask, how can I convert the next object to something like this manually.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2306
                    [idEmpleado] => 23
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2307
                    [idEmpleado] => 23
                )

        )

    [2123] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2292
                    [idEmpleado] => 2123
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2293
                    [idEmpleado] => 2123
                )


        )

)
```

To something like this:

```
Array
(
    [23] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2306
                    [idEmpleado] => 23
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2307
                    [idEmpleado] => 23
                )

        )

    [2123] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2292
                    [idEmpleado] => 2123
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [idTempHorario] => 2293
                    [idEmpleado] => 2123
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why `json_decode($o, true)` would not work for you. However another way to do the conversion is with a recursive function like this, which casts an object and its children to arrays:

```
function convert($obj) {
    $arr = (array)$obj;
    foreach ($arr as &$v) {
        if (is_object($v)) $v = convert($v);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/e5OE6)

Note that the demo also includes an example of `json_decode` producing exactly the same result...

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why wouldn't work neither, someday some piece of code I did in my house didn't work in job, and had to change the json_encode($a, true) to just json_encode($a) a few things more to make it works.